# How to compute $KR^{-q}(S^{p,0})$

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology

I am reading Atiyah's paper on $KR$-theory, and wondering how to compute $KR^{-q}(S^{p,0})$. The cases $p\geqslant 3$ may be simply deduced from the following isomorphism in the paper,
$$
KR^{-q}(X\times S^{p,0})\cong KR^{-q}(X)\oplus KR^{p+1-q}(X).
$$
Let $X$ be a point, $\mathrm{pt}$, then
$$
KR^{-q}(S^{p,0})\cong KR^{-q}(\mathrm{pt})\oplus KR^{p+1-q}(\mathrm{pt})\cong \pi_0({R_q})\oplus\pi_0(R_{q-p-1}).
$$
But how about the case with $p=2$? What is the group $KR^{-q}(S^{2,0})$? I cannot find the answer in the paper.

I am a PhD student in physics, not in mathmatics, so I might have made some stupid mistakes.

Thank you very much!